# Unity3D - Android pause screen - double click issue

Tags: android, unity, javascript

I made a pause script for the game im developing for android.

I added the script to the GUITexture I created and placed on the top right side of the screen.The issue stands at the part where if the player clicks the pause button then clicks resume then he wants to pause the game again.When he clicks pause the second time the buttons dont show up unless he clicks again.

This is the script :

```
#pragma strict

var paused = false;
var isButtonVisible : boolean = true;

function OnMouseDown(){
    this.paused = !this.paused;
    Time.timeScale = 0;
    isButtonVisible = true;
}

function OnGUI(){
    if ( isButtonVisible ) {
        if(this.paused){
            if (GUI.Button(Rect(Screen.width/2-100,Screen.height/2+3,200,50),"Restart")){
                Application.LoadLevel(Application.loadedLevel);
                Time.timeScale = 1;
                isButtonVisible = false;
            }

            if (GUI.Button(Rect(Screen.width/2-100,Screen.height/2-50,200,50),"Resume")){
                Time.timeScale = 1;
                isButtonVisible = false;
            }

            // Insert the rest of the pause menu logic
            if (GUI.Button(Rect(Screen.width/2-100,Screen.height/2+56,200,50),"Main Menu")){
                Application.LoadLevel ("MainMenu");
                isButtonVisible = false;
                Time.timeScale = 1;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Thank you.

Comment: And your question is?

Comment: How do I make it so when the player clicks pause for the second time it INSTANTLY opens the pause menu buttons and doesn't have to click twice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When any of the Restart, Resume, or Main Menu buttons are pressed you are not setting `this.paused` back to `false`.  The menu appears the first time because `this.paused` begins as `false`.  The second time the menu is opened, `this.paused` is already `true`, so it becomes `false` again at the statement:

```
this.paused = !this.paused;
```

Then your conditional `if (this.paused)` in `OnGUI` evaluates to `false` and your buttons are never drawn, until a second click when `this.paused` becomes `true` again.

In the future, you could debug problems like this by narrowing down what kind of conditions have to be satisfied to cause the problems you encounter.  In this case, your buttons were not drawing, so it *must* be the case that either (or both) `isButtonVisible` or `this.paused` were `false` in `OnGUI`.  Adding prints to inspect their values would have made it clear what was wrong.